# Returning data based on clicked marker using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

How do I get the data according to the [marker](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#marker) I clicked on?

```
for(i in data) {
    var title = data[i].title,
    id = data[i].id,      
    position = data[i].position,      
    kriteria = data[i].data.kriteria,     
    iconUrl =  data[i].icon.url,
    pa_judul = data[i].data.pa_judul,
    marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(position), 
    {

        icon:  L.icon({
            iconUrl:   iconUrl,
        })

    }, 
    {title: title},

    ).addTo(map);

    marker.bindPopup('ID: '+ id ).on('click', function(e) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#ModalDetail').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        });
    });
    markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
}
```

`console.log(data)` returns the whole array:

[image]

When I change to `console.log(data[i]);` I get undefined message:

[image]

If I change to `console.log(data[0])` or `data[1]` and `data[2]` the results is not error and I can get the data:

[image]

Only for `marker.bindpopup` this working fine, but for on click it's not working.

[image]

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24501655/125400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve what you want by adding custom property `myID` (could be any name) to marker and setting it to index value `i`. In this way the correct index to `data` array will be available at click event.

Something like this:

```
for(i in data) {
    var title = data[i].title,
    id = data[i].id,      
    position = data[i].position,      
    kriteria = data[i].data.kriteria,     
    iconUrl =  data[i].icon.url,
    pa_judul = data[i].data.pa_judul;

    var marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(position), 
    {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: iconUrl,
      }),
      title: title
    }
    ).addTo(map);
    marker.myID = i;

    marker.bindPopup('ID: '+ id ).on('click', function(e) {
      var i = e.target.myID;
      console.log(data[i]);
      $('#ModalDetail').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
      });
    });
    markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, you saved my day.